# What is KernelEventAgent in Activity Monitor?

Tags: mac, cpu, activity-monitor

A process called 'KernelEventAgent' is using up all my CPU. I have to force quit it all the time because otherwise everything else slows down..

Comment: Please update your question with your macOS version, otherwise it's just guesswork you're asking from us. What have you done to find out what the process is responsible for? Killing off Kernel related processes is really not recommended, especially if you don't know what they do. From `man KernelEventAgent` - `The KernelEventAgent utility is responsible for displaying disk full and unresponsive file server messages.  It is not intended to be run directly, but rather started by the system.` Have you checked you are not low on disk space or have problems connecting to any file servers?

Comment: I am running MacOS Ventura 13.0 Beta. It may be because I have only 10 gb left of storage but I never had any problems with this in the past... I am using a WD 8TB MyBook recently and running a Plex media server to make it available on the network. Also, I have installed (but not always running) Cisco to connect to university networks. Maybe it helps to narrow down the problem ? Killing the process has never resulted in problems for daily use at all. It just randomly starts up (even if no drives or networks are connected) and uses up to 90% of my CPU.